# Marklogic Corb export data as compress

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

Can MarkLogic Corb export as a zip for every two thousand XML files? I appreciate any example you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing each of the docs using [`PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportToFileTask`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#PROCESS-TASK)
and [`POST-BATCH-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.PostBatchUpdateFileTask`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#POST-BATCH-TASK), then you can enable the option [`EXPORT_FILE_AS_ZIP=true`](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#user-content-xport_file_as_zip) and it will compress the files in the directory using `EXPORT_FILE_NAME`, `EXPORT-FILE-DIR`, optionally `EXPORT_FILE_PART_EXT` (defaults to using ".zip").

```
XCC-CONNECTION-URI=xcc://user:password@localhost:8000
URIS-MODULE=/path/to/uris.xqy|ADHOC
PROCESS-MODULE=/path/to/process.xqy|ADHOC

PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportToFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-DIR=/tmp
EXPORT_FILE_NAME=MyExport
POST-BATCH-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.PostBatchUpdateFileTask
EXPORT_FILE_AS_ZIP=true
```

You can't limit how many docs to put into the zip with the built-in PostBatchUpdateFileTask, but you could extend that class and configure your own custom POST-BATCH-TASK class to be used instead, or you could break up the CoRB job into sets of 2,000 URIs at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  But the corb above is appending the content of doc1.xml and doc2.xml into a single document after zip. I'm looking for the corb zip file that has doc1.xml and doc2.xml. When the user unzips will have two documents..

Comment: did you configure `ExportToFile` or `ExportBatchToFile`?